# Get ArrayList from another Class

Tags: java, arraylist, data-exchange

what I'm trying to do is:
- Scan a directory
- For each folder found add its name to an ArrayList
- Bring this ArrayList to Main Class and print it.

Here's my ScanDirs Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ScanDirs {

    private ArrayList<String> locations;
    public void scan() {
        File rootDir = new File("./src/data");
        locations = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File f : rootDir.listFiles()) {
            String fName = f.getName();
            locations.add(fName);
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getScan(){
        return locations;
    }
}
```

And here's the Main Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    private static ScanDirs scanObject;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        scanObject = new ScanDirs();
        ArrayList<String> list = scanObject.getScan();
        System.out.println(list);

    }

}
```

My output is: null
Why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called `scan()` method anywhere in your code. So, simply calling `getScan()` will result in un-intialized locations value i.e. `null`.

what you can do is simply call `scan()` method before calling `getScan()` method like:

```
        scanObject = new ScanDirs();
        scanObject.scan();  // calling scan method
        ArrayList<String> list = scanObject.getScan();
        System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: @user3276178 yeah and from these silly mistakes we learn to improve :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ScanDirs()` constructor is using the default constructor (which sets everything to their default values), the `locations` list will be set to null. If you want to set the locations list to something, create a constructor for the ScanDirs class:

```
public ScanDirs(ArrayList<String> locations){
this.locations = locations;
}
```

or you could also do this:

```
public ScanDirs(){
locations = new ArrayList<String>();
this.scan();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below code will do for you change below getScan method

```
public ArrayList<String> getScan(){
this.scan();    
return locations;
}
```

and blow change for better readability.

```
File folder = new File("./src/data");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
    location.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `Scan()` method in the `main.java` file, or you need to add it to the constructor of the `ScanDirs` class.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have not called `scan()` anywhere.
So u should add this statement in main(), before calling `getScan()` .

`scanObject.scan();`

This will definetly make it run.